# Iterate over json array with python 2.7

Tags: json, python-2.7

I want to iterate over json array that looks likes this.

```
[
{"key":"value"},
{"key2":"value2"},
{"key3":"value3"},
]
```

I have tried with json library but it's not possible to iterate over it. The index is not añways **0** but succesive

```
json_result = json.loads(json_var)

print(json_result[0])
print(json_result[0]["key"])

print(json_result[1])
print(json_result[1]["key1"])
```

comes with:

```
{"key":"value"}
value
{"key1":"value1"}
value1
```

So, I would like to get values without accessing their names. something like this:

```
for x in json_result:
 print(json_result[0][x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for i in list_json_var:
    for key in i:
        print(i[key])
```